# RecursiveIteratorIterator loops too many times with LEAVES_ONLY, works with SELF_FIRST

Tags: php

This is a strange problem and I've been pulling my hair out over it for a while now.  Basically, I have an array of arrays (2 levels).  I am using a `RecursiveIterator` to "pretend" this array has more levels than it does.  My goal is to "group" the array by 2 elements.

I created my own class that `implements RecursiveIterator`, then I threw it through a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to loop over it.  Each "child" level in the iterator is one of the keys in the array.

Let me give an example.  Here's the array of emails I have:

```
$data = [
  [
    'address' => 'example@example.com',
    'emailType' => 'reminder',
    'data' => 'Test Reminder'
  ],
  [
    'address' => 'example2@example.com',
    'emailType' => 'reminder',
    'data' => 'Another Test Reminder'
  ],
  [
    'address' => 'example@example.com',
    'emailType' => 'reminder',
    'data' => 'Yet Another Test Reminder'
  ],
  [
    'address' => 'example@example.com',
    'emailType' => 'order',
    'data' => 'Testing Order'
  ]
];
```

First I want to group this by the `address`, then by the `emailType`.  If they match, then group by the `data` values.

So, I want to see the following:

```
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending order to example@example.com
-> Testing Order
Sending reminder to example2@example.com
-> Another Test Reminder
```

I have got this working with my custom `RecursiveIterator` class (and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`).

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new MyIterator($data), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach($iter as $key=>$val){
    if(!is_array($val)) continue;
    echo "Sending {$iter->getEmailType()} to {$key}\n";
    if(count($iter->getInnerIterator()) > 1){
      echo '-> '.implode(', ', $val['data'])."\n";
    }
    else{
        echo '-> '.$val['data']."\n";
    }
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/179753

The problem here is that this is using `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`, which means I need `if(!is_array($val)) continue;`.  I wanted to get rid of that, so I tried to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` instead, to just print the children.  That's where the issue is.  When I change that, I get too may iterations over my loop and repeated data.

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new MyIterator($data), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);
foreach($iter as $key=>$val){
    if(!is_array($val)) continue;
    echo "Sending {$iter->getEmailType()} to {$key}\n";
    if(count($iter->getInnerIterator()) > 1){
      echo '-> '.implode(', ', $val['data'])."\n";
    }
    else{
        echo '-> '.$val['data']."\n";
    }
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/179754

This outputs:

```
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending order to example@example.com
-> Testing Order
Sending reminder to example2@example.com
-> Another Test Reminder
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending order to example@example.com
-> Testing Order
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending reminder to example@example.com
-> Test Reminder, Yet Another Test Reminder
Sending order to example@example.com
-> Testing Order
```

The heck is going on?  Why doesn't `LEAVES_ONLY` *only* print the "leaves", like it's supposed to?

Here is the code for my iterator.  It's rather long, but it seems to get the job done.

```
<?php

/**
 * Iterate recursively over an array
 */
class MyIterator implements RecursiveIterator, Countable{
    private $data, $groups, $currentGroup, $position, $subPosition, $savedSubPosition, $seenRows;

    // Prepare our iterator
    public function __construct($array, $currentGroup=0, $savedSubPosition=[]){
        $this->data = $array;
        $this->groups = ['address', 'emailType', null];
        $this->currentGroup = $currentGroup;

        $this->savedSubPosition = $savedSubPosition;

        // The class is loaded, let's go to the very beginning
        $this->rewind();
    }

    /**
     * From Iterator
     * http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php
     */

    // Reset to 0 position
    // Return void
    function rewind(){
        // -1, so we can call next()
        $this->position = -1;
        $this->subPosition = -1;
        $this->seenRows = [];

        // Let's get the "first" element, if there is one
        $this->next();
    }

    // Return current position
    function current($doNotMarkSeen=FALSE){
        $group = $this->getGroupName();

        if(is_null($group)){
            // Reduce the entire array into one array
            // Thus the last group will *always* have 1 (or 0) elements
            return array_reduce($this->data, function($ret, $val){
                if(empty($ret)){ // First iteration
                    return $val;
                }
                elseif(is_string($ret['data'])){  // Second Iteration
                    $ret['data'] = [$ret['data'], $val['data']];
                    return $ret;
                }
                else{  // Third+ Iteration
                    $ret['data'][] = $val['data'];
                    return $ret;
                }
            }, []);
        }
        else{
            $rowVal = $this->data[$this->position][$group];
            is_array($rowVal) && ($rowVal = $rowVal[$this->subPosition]);

            return $doNotMarkSeen ? $rowVal : ($this->seenRows[] = $rowVal);
        }
    }

    // Return current key
    function key(){
        // In this case, the key is the email address
        // yes, the key might wind up being the same across iterations
        // Well, it's only the email on the last group, otherwise it's a number
        $group = $this->getGroupName();
        return is_null($group) ? $this->getEmailAddress() : $this->position;
    }

    // Shift position by one
    // Return void
    function next(){
        // We need to shift to the next group member,
        // that means either the next email address, or the next emailType
        do{
            $group = $this->getGroupName();
            $incrementMain = true;

            // Which one do we need to increment?
            if($this->subPosition > -1 && isset($this->data[$this->position]) && count($this->data[$this->position][$group]) > $this->subPosition){
                $this->subPosition++;
                $incrementMain = !(count($this->data[$this->position][$group]) > $this->subPosition);
            }


            if($incrementMain){
                $this->position++;
                $this->subPosition = -1;

                if(isset($this->data[$this->position]) && !is_null($group) && is_array($this->data[$this->position][$group])){
                    $this->subPosition++;
                }
            }
        } while($this->_hasSeenRow());
    }

    // Is there data at our current position?
    // Return boolean
    function valid(){
        // This is called *after* next() (or rewind()) is
        // The last group is weird and does not follow this formula
        $group = $this->getGroupName();
        if(is_null($group)){
            // We are doing array_reduce, so there's only one "position"
            return count($this->data) > 0 && $this->position === 0;
        }
        else{
            $isValid = isset($this->data[$this->position]);
            if($isValid){
                $validPosition = count($this->data) > $this->position;
                if($validPosition && !is_null($group) && is_array($this->data[$this->position][$group])){
                    $validPosition = count($this->data[$this->position][$group]) > $this->subPosition;
                }
                return $validPosition;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here's where the fun is.  Do we have any child arrays?
     *
     * From RecursiveIterator
     * http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php
     */

    // Are there any child arrays?
    // Return boolean
    function hasChildren(){
        return !is_null($this->getGroupName());
    }

    // Return an iterator for the child array
    function getChildren(){
        // Send it the same array.  It's not actually 2-d, we're just pretending it is
        $groupName = $this->getGroupName();
        $thisValue = $this->current(true);
        $subPosition = $this->subPosition;

        !is_null($groupName) && ($this->savedSubPosition[$groupName] = $subPosition);

        // Note to self: array_filter preserves keys.
        return new self(array_values(array_filter($this->data, function($a) use($groupName, $thisValue, $subPosition){
            $val = $a[$groupName];
            return (is_array($val) ? $val[$subPosition] : $val) === $thisValue;
        })), $this->currentGroup+1, $this->savedSubPosition);
    }

    /**
     * From GroupIterator
     */

    // Return the current group name
    function getGroupName(){
        return $this->groups[$this->currentGroup];
    }

    /**
     * From Countable
     * http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php
     */
    function count($mode=COUNT_NORMAL){  // <- $mode is only passed in PHP 5.6
        switch($mode){
            case COUNT_NORMAL:
                $groupName = $this->getGroupName();

                if(!is_null($groupName)){
                    $allVals = array_map(function($a) use($groupName){
                        return $a[$groupName];
                    }, $this->data);
                    if(isset($allVals[0]) && is_array($allVals[0])){
                        $allVals = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $allVals);
                    }

                    return count(array_unique($allVals));
                }
                else{
                    return count($this->data);
                }
                break;
            case COUNT_RECURSIVE:  // <- Only exists in PHP 5.6
                // TODO: Count *all* groups from this one forward, and add 'em up
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom functions
     */
    function getEmailType(){
        return $this->_getRowVal('emailType');
    }
    function getEmailAddress(){
        return $this->_getRowVal('address');
    }

    /**
     * Helper functions
     */
    private function _hasSeenRow(){
        $groupName = $this->getGroupName();
        return ($this->valid() && !is_null($groupName)) ? in_array($this->current(true), $this->seenRows, true) : false;
    }
    private function _getRowVal($name){
        $val = $this->data[$this->position][$name];
        return is_array($val) ? $val[!empty($this->savedSubPosition) ? $this->savedSubPosition[$name] : $this->subPosition] : $val;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That's a pretty long way of grouping together the entries by `address,emailType`. Wouldn't a custom sort be a shorter and more readable solution? +1

Comment: @halfer: Yeah, probably.  I made a `RecursiveIterator` for another part of this project and it works lovely.  In that case, a custom sort wouldn't work (I tried).  So, I wanted to keep using `RecursiveIterator` because I like them (https://xkcd.com/208/).  I guess I could make a better solution, but I'm still kinda curious why `LEAVES_ONLY` is acting weird.

Comment: I've only used RecursiveIterators a bit, but the thing that first comes to me is that there doesn't seem to be any need for recursion. That would only be required if each entry (of the three key-value pairs) could have children that themselves have entries. I guess you know that though, since you say you are pretending that the array has more levels than it does. Would you expand on that, in your question?

Comment: @halfer: I'm just trying to "group" the array, and (for some reason) the first thing I thought of was recursion.  So, I hacked this up.  I did realize that only the final level would have entries, not all the levels.  But, I fixed that issue, by returning either the emailAddress or emailType in that case, and returning an array as the final child.

Comment: I guess I am just over-complicating things with this, but it was what I thought of to solve this issue.  It "works", but I guess it's not perfect or even the best solution.

Comment: In this situation I'd write the custom sorter, even though iterators are nice to play with. It will be much less code (10-15 lines, I expect). Also new devs approaching the code in your post will wonder why the `current()` method needs to call `array_reduce()` on the whole data structure - you don't want to make their brain melt! `;-)`.

Comment: @halfer: ...Yeah, you're probably right.  I should just do that.  Thanks :-D  ...And, maybe I *DO* want to melt some brains ;-)